# solving Tower of Hanoi recursively

Tags: python

I know the idea behind the Tower of Hanoi and know the algorithm but I am having trouble implementing it.

```
class Hanoi:
    def __init__(self, n):
       == code==

    def move(self, src, dst):
   =code for moving the disk from source to destination==

    def spare(self, src, dst):
    ==Returns the peg which is not src and dst==

    def print_pegs(self):


h = Hanoi(4)

def hanoi(n, src, dst):         
        if n==1:
           h.move(src,dst)
        else:
            spare=h.spare(src,dst)
            hanoi(n-1,src,spare)
            hanoi(1,src,dst)
            hanoi(n-1,spare,dst)

hanoi(4, 0, 2)
```

The problem I am having is I don't know how to combine the recursive definition with the class function to move the disks.

Comment: Is this a syntax question?  I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: def hanoi is a syntax to go recursively but i need to add it there somewhere h.move(src,spare) etc but i am having trouble how to do it

Comment: There is a [MIT lecture](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00sc-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-spring-2011/unit-1/lecture-6-recursion/) that deals with the problem.

Comment: _"don't know how to combine the recursive definition with the class fuction"_ and _"i want to leave the class as it is and put the recursion in the hanoi function"_ are contradictory. What do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the recursive calls inside the body of `move()` and `spare()` and move the logic of your function `hanoi()` into the relevant methods

so

```
class Hanoi(object):

    # snip

    def move(self, src, dst):

        # your logic goes here
        # example of a recursive call
        self.move(foo, bar)
```

Comment: is there a way to do it in hanoi function, i want to leave the class as it is and put the recursion in the hanoi function

Comment: You don't need to create a class, just write your functions directly. Are you using a textbook with examples in Java?